# Running bundle switches Ruby versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, bundle

So t I am using RVM and have set it to use Ruby 1.9.3. I downloaded a tutorial app, but after I run bundle and 'which ruby' my machine shows I am using Ruby 1.8.7 for all other projects.

Is this possible? What is bundle actually doing?

Shouldn't it just use 1.8.7 for just that project?

How can I make the tutorial switch to using 1.9.3 and make it not bundle 1.8.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

best way to avoid version switching is to use a .rvmrc,you can create an .rvmrc file in the application’s root directory. RVM recgonizes an .rvmrc file in a directory and loads the gemset specified inside.following is an example for creating an .rvmrc for rails 3.1 using ruby 1.9.3

```
echo "rvm ruby193@rails31" > .rvmrc
```

Using an .rvmrc file means you’ll automatically be using the correct Rails and gem version when you run your application on your local machine. This works best if you create an rvm gemset specifically for your application.

[RVM best practises](https://rvm.io/rvm/best-practices)

Answer (score 0):

[Bundler](http://gembundler.com/rationale.html) will only help you manage your gems. The ruby version is controlled by RVM.
Seems like your rvm is not properly installed. Check if the ruby being used your shell is the one being managed by rvm. `$ which ruby` should return something like `/home/alexandre/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby`

RVM installation is quite complicated. I would recommend you check yours.